# Jquery: How to set the order in which handlers are called

Tags: jquery, events

I want the document click to be called before everything.

```
//This is registered first

$(document).on('touchstart',function(){});
```

After my app starts running i add a few items which also listens to touchstart. So the documents touchstart is never called. How do i make 'document' the priority. if i don't do e.preventDefault(); or e.stopPropaggation(); the other elements should be called.

Comment: Can you build a fiddle ? The document level event handler should also be called if you don't prevent the propagation in some way.

Comment: Do you check is `ontouchstart in document`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny OP precises he doesn't stop it (if I get the question).

Comment: @dystroy sorry... misread it

Comment: other listner is a drag plugin ... so i guess it stops propagation. I want my script to run before the plugin

Comment: do you have a `return false` in any of the handlers

Comment: No i don't. But the plugin might

Comment: Why don't you just also bind the event handler to your dragable elements ?

Comment: Won't it create problems?... I add touchstart to all the elements.. The plugin will add it again ... will it work fine?

Comment: Normally yes, but I don't see what you can do useful on touchstart if the elements are dragged elsewhere, apart simply noticing something happens.

Comment: I have to close all open menus on any touchevent and then restore normal touch functionality.

Comment: how about pageinit instead of touchstart?

Comment: yeah that happens only once... my menus come and go all the time.

Comment: @dystroy adding touch start to everything sort of worked.. had to write work arounds for a couple of things... Thanks mate. :)